# Why won't my concern's methods run from the console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport-concern

I created a concern to add an `enum` and `class_methods`

```
# app/models/concerns/addressable.rb
module Addressable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    enum address_province: {
      Queen: 'Q',
      Bear:  'B'
    }
  end

  class_methods do
    def options_for_cities
      %w[a b]
    end

    def scream
      'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
    end
  end
end

# app/models/order.rb
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  include Addressable
end
```

However, when I try to execute any of these methods in `Order`, they don't work.

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 3004
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.2)

irb(main):001:0> Order.options_for_cities
NoMethodError: undefined method `options_for_cities' for Order (call 'Order.connection' to establish a connection):Class
Did you mean?  options_for_with_status
    from (irb):1
irb(main):002:0> Order.scream
NoMethodError: undefined method `scream' for Order (call 'Order.connection' to establish a connection):Class
    from (irb):2
irb(main):003:0> Order.address_provinces
NoMethodError: undefined method `address_provinces' for Order (call 'Order.connection' to establish a connection):Class
    from (irb):3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you have a conflict with existent Addressable module. Try changing your module name to different one.

Answer (score -1):

These isn't a problem. All that's happening is the connection is not instantiated until it's needed.

try

```
Order.connection
```

than

```
Order.count
```

you get desire count for Order.